# Why is Orchard so slow when executing a content item query?

Tags: sql, performance, orchardcms

Lets say i want to query all Orchard user IDs and i want to include those users that have been removed (aka soft deleted) also. The DB contains around 1000 users.

**Option A** - **takes around 2 minutes**

```
Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager lContentManager = ...;

lContentManager
  .Query<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart, Orchard.Users.Models.UserPartRecord>(Orchard.ContentManagement.VersionOptions.AllVersions)
  .List()
  .Select(u => u.Id)
  .ToList();
```

**Option B** - executes with **almost unnoticeable delay**

```
Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.Users.Models.UserPartRecord> UserRepository = ...;

UserRepository .Fetch(u => true).Select(u => u.Id).ToList();
```

I don't see any SQL queries being executed in SQL Profiler when using Option A. I guess it has something to do with NHibernate or caching.

Is there any way to optimize **Option A**?

Comment: What if you switch `.List()` with the `.Select()` part?

Comment: @devqon I can't switch these as `Query()` returns a `IContentQuery<>` which does not provide a `Select()` method.

Comment: Interesting...  I had some issues with nhibernate, but in older Orchard version. Which version?

Comment: @urbanit It's version 1.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because the `IContentManager` version is accessing the data via `InfoSet` (basically an xml representation of the data), where as the `IRepository` version uses the actual DB table itself.

I seem to remember reading that though Infoset is great in many cases, when you're dealing with larger datasets with sorting / filtering it is more efficient to go direct to the table, as using Infoset requires each xml fragment to be parsed and elements extracted before you get to the data.

Since 'the shift', Orchard uses both so you can use whichever method best suits to your needs. I can't find the article that explained it now, but this explains the shift & infosets quite nicely:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you

Hope that helps you?